# Pig-Loading Json file which is present on Azure Storage

Tags: json, azure, apache-pig

I am trying to load a Json file (`Email_Master.json`) using a pig script which is present on Azure storage container. The json file has been generated by a pig script and stored onto azure container. Below is the image how the file looks on container.

[image]

I am facing the error while loading the file using pig script through Powershell

> ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1131: Could not find schema file

The command used is

```
a = LOAD '$Azure_Path/Email_Master.json' USING JsonLoader();
```

How to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Default Container which is specified while provisioning HdInsight Cluster.The schema and Header files are storing in Default container.